# How I can put amount of star as amount of number in awk?

Tags: awk

I am new in awk and don't know is there any way to put star after the number how many people got that average and another questions is there any better way to check the average instead of if(switch also)?

**input text-**

```
Peter 70 70 70
Andras 85 85 85 85 85
Maria 89
Bea 88 88
Zoltan 63 65 63 65 
Zsolt 95 95
```

**Here is my awk code:**

```
    {
for( i=2; i<=NF; ++i){
    p[$1]+=$i;   
}

count[$1]+=NF-1;
}
END{
for(n in p){
an=p[n]/count[n];
    if(an<=9){
        a+=1;
    }
    if(an>=10 && an<=19){
        b+=1;
    }
    if(an>=20 && an<=29){
        c+=1;
    }
    if(an>=30 && an<=39){
        d+=1;
    }
    if(an>=40 && an<=49){
        e+=1;
    }
    if(an>=50 && an<=59){
        f+=1;
    }
    if(an>=60 && an<=69){
        g+=1;
    }
    if(an>=70 && an<=79){
        h+=1;
    }
    if(an>=80 && an<=89){
        k+=1;
    }
    if(an>=90 && an<=99){
        l+=1;
    }
    if(an>=100){
        m+=1;
    }
}
printf("0 -   9: %d\n",a);
printf("10 - 19: %d\n",b);
printf("20 - 29: %d\n",c);
printf("30 - 39: %d\n",d);
printf("40 - 49: %d\n",e);
printf("50 - 59: %d\n",f);
printf("60 - 69: %d\n",g);
printf("70 - 79: %d\n",h);
printf("80 - 89: %d\n",k);
printf("90 - 99: %d\n",l);
printf("100: %d\n",m);


}
```

[This result I have now (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkiVM.png)

[but I need this way (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjwSZ.png)

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet might to be just print in a loop:

```
    {
for( i=2; i<=NF; ++i){
    p[$1]+=$i;   
}

count[$1]+=NF-1;
}
END{
for(n in p){
an=p[n]/count[n];
    if(an<=9){
        a+=1;
    }
    if(an>=10 && an<=19){
        b+=1;
    }
    if(an>=20 && an<=29){
        c+=1;
    }
    if(an>=30 && an<=39){
        d+=1;
    }
    if(an>=40 && an<=49){
        e+=1;
    }
    if(an>=50 && an<=59){
        f+=1;
    }
    if(an>=60 && an<=69){
        g+=1;
    }
    if(an>=70 && an<=79){
        h+=1;
    }
    if(an>=80 && an<=89){
        k+=1;
    }
    if(an>=90 && an<=99){
        l+=1;
    }
    if(an>=100){
        m+=1;
    }
}
printf("0 -   9: %d",a);for(i=0;i<a;i++) printf "* "; printf "\n";
printf("10 - 19: %d",b);for(i=0;i<b;i++) printf "* "; printf "\n";
printf("20 - 29: %d\n",c);
printf("30 - 39: %d\n",d);
printf("40 - 49: %d\n",e);
printf("50 - 59: %d\n",f);
printf("60 - 69: %d\n",g);
printf("70 - 79: %d\n",h);
printf("80 - 89: %d\n",k);
printf("90 - 99: %d\n",l);
printf("100: %d\n",m);


}
```

Comment: Your code is already pretty verbose. If you could update your question with your starting data I have a suspicion this code could be rewritten to be more succinct. Ultimately your question is just "How do I repeat a character N times in awk" and the answer there is a loop. You could stick this loop in a function that returns a string containing your stars that is then printed as part of your one `printf`as one option.